# Как в Trampermonkey выбрать и кликнуть по options в select

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

```
<select name="third_rubric" id="third_rubric">
<option value="00">Выбор подрубрики</option>
<option value="110101">Компьютеры</option>
<option value="110107">Куплю</option>
<option value="110102">Мониторы</option>
<option value="110103">Ноутбуки</option>
<option value="110104">Принтеры</option>
<option value="110106">Прочее</option>
<option value="110105">Сканеры</option>
</select>
```

Очень бы хотелось, чтобы скрипт автоматом выбирал из выпадающего списка "Компьютеры"

Вот, к примеру пишу этот код, чтобы проверить, работают ли все эти .options в обезьянке:

```
var select, value, text;
select = document.getElementById("third_rubric"); // Выбираем  select по id
value = select.options[0].value; // Значение value для выбранного option
text = select.options[0].text; // Текстовое значение для выбранного option
alert("Value: " + value + "\nТекст: " + text); // Вывод алерта для проверки значений
```

Консоль выводит ошибку.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null

Помогите, дайте ссылку на скрипт - пример. Сам 2 дня искал. В JS я ноль.

Answer (score 1):

```
var select;
select = document.getElementById("third_rubric"); // Выбираем  select по id

for(i=0; i < select.options.length; i++)
{
 if(select.options[i].text == "Компьютеры") 
 {
   select.options[i].setAttribute('selected',true)
 }
}
```